# Latex Error: package too old

Tags: expl3

I am compiling a document and am running into trouble because of a supposedly outdated package. I already googled the error and found several solutions, all of which suggest I should update my environment, tex distro, and the package itself. All of which I did. Nothing of which helped :( So I am here.

The error when compiling I get is:

```
error: Package lipsum Error: Package expl3 too old.
// ...
warning: You have requested, on input line 28, version `2018/10/31' of package expl3, but only version `2017/05/13 L3 programming layer (loader) ' is available.
```

I am using MikTex 2.9.7 on Windows with TexStudio. All updated to the newest versions. Packages updated to the newest versions too.

So I went to update the lipsum package. And the l3packages and l3kernel packages (that ship the ekpl3 package). Nothing helps.

I went and checked the file expl3.sty in `MikTex 2.9/tex/latex/l3kernel` just to find it states `\def\ExplFileDate{2019-07-01}%`. So it IS up to date - or what?

Because compiling still yields the SAME error!

Someone knows how to fix this?

Comment: check the log (which shows the full path to the included file) the usual issue in miktex is that you need to update both admin and user installations.

Comment: probably you have somewhere old version of this package. as mention @DavidCarlisle, you need to update both admin and user instalation (by use of MikTeX Console).